# What are the benefits of Spring Actionscript considering Dynamic Proxies and Reflection is limited

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, spring, spring-actionscript

What are the benefits of Spring Actionscript considering [Dynamic Proxies](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/ASC-3136) are not possible in the current version of Actionscript and Reflection is quite limited.

So for example I could specify my object creation in an XML application context, but why would I do that when I can simply specify that in code, and hence take advantage of static type checking etc.

It is by no means my intent to belittle the work done on Spring Actionscript but more to find an application for it in my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides XML configuration, Spring ActionScript also supports MXML configuration. The type of config (XML, MXML) depends on the use cases your application needs to support. For the reasons you mention, it makes perfect sense to configure most of the context in MXML, but I would encourage you to externalize the config of service endpoints in every case.

In a past project we opted for XML config since the configuration was generated at runtime when a user logged on to the application. Depending on the user credentials, different endpoints and various different settings were used. We could not have done this elegantly with static MXML configs.

Both config types have their strengths and weaknesses, and it's up to you to decide what type you want to use. I think we could even support a mixture of MXML and XML quite easily actually if that would make sense. As soon as we have Dynamic Proxies and class loading, XML config will make a lot more sense.

Comment: +1 Hey Christophe, I was hoping you would jump in on this. I didn't know about the MXML configuration option, which does make a lot more sense that XML in a lot of cases. I still feel that Spring for AS is really being artificially held back due to the lack of Dyn Proxies etc. And that it is potentially a useful tool, but for now a lot of the potential uses are not possible, such as injecting logging as a cross cutting concern etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with Sean in the general sense that trying to force Flex inside of the Java box is generally a bad idea. As many similarities as there are, Flex is not Java.

That being said, there are plenty of reasons why you might want to have some of your configuration in an external XML file, not the least of which is in the use case of configuring your service destinations and endpoints, where you may have a need to be able to change the endpoint URI without having to recompile your application.

Answer (score 0):

There are several projects available that are simply misguided ports of philosophies from other platforms. Whenever starting in on a new platform, I think the best thing to do is figure out how people are effectively developing and go from there.

I say all of that because I think *all* of the java-esque frameworks for flex/flash leave you worse off than you started. You do need dependency injection, but there are good as3/mxml-friendly frameworks for that (Mate, Swiz). There is absolutely no point in using xml when you can use mxml, which is strongly typed.